# Firestore Storage Rules Chat

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a chat application in which images can be sent, I want to write the security rules for Storage so that only what is in the chats collection and in the UserIds array can send images, but it always tells me that I am not authorized.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
   match /Users/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    match /Chats/{chatId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if chatRoomPermission(chatId)
    }
    function chatRoomPermission(chatId) {
      return request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Chats/$(chatId)).data.userIds;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Security rules are meaningless without the code that exercises them, and the data it depends on. Please edit your question to include the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem and the data you're checking, and makes sure to also log any values that your rules depend on in that code (such as the UID) and the chat ID.

Comment: In my question I put the code snippet, is it not showing? `

Comment: You shared the security rules, but not the code fro your app. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: here you say that from the storage security rules you cannot access the cloud firestore database

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60801027/firebase-storage-security-rules-and-firestore

Comment: Ah, I completely overloooked that you're trying to read from **Firestore** inside your **Storage** rules. That is indeed not possible.

Comment: I'm thinking of using custom claims or metadata on images, regarding custom claims, it shouldn't exceed 1,000 bytes, but is this the total or the independent claim? let's imagine I have a user who is in 10 chat rooms, it would have 10 properties in the custom claim are the chat id and yours

Comment: The total of all custom claims cannot exceed 1000 bytes.

Comment: umm, what alternatives do I have? to make chat images private to that group and chat participants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as a Community Wiki as it's based on Frank's Comments:

Reading data from Firestore directly in the Firebase Rules of your Storage is not possible and the alternative os using custom claims is not possible since they cannot exceed 1000 bytes.

The alternative you have in this case would be to create the control in your app's code or in a Cloud Function.

Comment: I think I'll create a cloud functions endpoint and make a database call to verify that the id is in the chat group and then upload the image. Another option is in the metadata, but I see the drawback that when users join the group or leave it, they update the metadata of all the images in that group chat.

Comment: I would say that the Cloud Function apporach would be the most appropriated approach to this problem, since it would be transparent to any users or client devices. I will edit that into the answer.